# n1ql multiple unnest in select statement with multiple where condition

Tags: sql++

Following is one of the sample document in couchbase.

```
{ 
  "name":"abc",
  "friends":["a","b","c"],
  "bestfriends":["x","y","z"]
}
```

I want to display "name" based on certain condition on "friends" and "bestfriends".

**n1ql Query**

```
select s.name from userdetails s
unnest s.friends as f
unnest s.bestfriends as bf
where f="a" or bf="a"
```

The above query works fine, if both the array ( friends, bestfriends) are not empty array.

but, even if any one of the array is empty array (ie. "bestfriends":[]), the result is null. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LEFT OUTER UNNEST in both cases.